# SQL Server Procedure Cache memory details

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to know what is the maximum caching allowed for Stored procedures and how many memory is occupied.

Is there a way to know it ?

Answer (score 2):

The execution cache is part of the buffer pool and cannot exceed the maximum server memory, which can be viewed using EXEC sp_configure.  You can do something like this to view the usage (src: http://blog.extreme-advice.com/2012/11/24/find-buffer-pool-usage-of-database-in-sql-server/),

```
SELECT
database_id AS DatabaseID,
DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName,
COUNT(file_id) * 8/1024.0 AS BufferSizeInMB
FROM
sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
GROUP BY
DB_NAME(database_id),database_id
ORDER BY
BufferSizeInMB DESC
GO
```